# React POST request to java spring rest API cors error

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, rest

so I'm working on setting up the foundation of a full stack application with a java spring backend, eventually a mysql database, and a react frontend. I am currently able to send my backend 'user' repository to the react frontend with the following code

User Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    public User(){
    }
    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email){
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    
}
```

User Rest controller:

```
CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("users")
public List<User> getUsers(){
    return this.userRepository.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/signin")
public void login(@RequestBody User user) { 
System.out.println(user);
   }
}
```

In the backend repository I am creating three fake users, and displaying them in react as such:

```
import react from "react";
import UserService from "../services/UserService";

class UserComponent extends react.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        UserService.getUsers().then((response) => {
            this.setState({users: response.data})
        });
    }

    sendUsers(){
        return this.state;
    }

    render (){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className = "text-center">Users List</h1>
                <table className = "table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td> User Id</td>
                            <td> User First Name</td>
                            <td> User Last Name</td>
                            <td> User Email</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.users.map(
                                user =>
                                <tr key= {user.id}>
                                    <td> {user.id}</td>
                                    <td> {user.firstName}</td>
                                    <td> {user.lastName}</td>
                                    <td> {user.email}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UserComponent
```

This is all working fine, until I try to send a username and password back to my java spring rest api, I am new to full stack development and I'm sure what I'm doing is a basic mistake. Here is my code with the getUsers() function that is working, and the login() function that is not working

```
import axios from "axios";
import authHeader from "./auth-header";

const USERS_REST_API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/users';
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api';

class UserService{
    login(username, password) {
        console.log(username);
        console.log(password);
        return axios
          .post(API_URL + "/signin", {
            username,
            password
          })
          .then(response => {
            if (response.data.accessToken) {
              localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
            }
    
            return response.data;
          });
      }

    getUsers(){
        console.log(USERS_REST_API_URL);
        return axios.get(USERS_REST_API_URL);
    }
    
    getPublicContent() {
    return axios.get(API_URL + 'all');
  }

  getUserBoard() {
    return axios.get(API_URL + 'user', { headers: authHeader() });
  }

  getModeratorBoard() {
    return axios.get(API_URL + 'mod', { headers: authHeader() });
  }

  getAdminBoard() {
    return axios.get(API_URL + 'admin', { headers: authHeader() });
  }
}

export default new UserService();
```

As you can see I'm POST'ing a valid username and password to 'http://localhost:8080/api/signin', and being met with the following error
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/signin' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

You can see in the top of my second code segment I have in my rest controller to allow crossorigins from localhost:3000, and I am able to receive the user data just fine on my react frontend, any idea's as to what's causing this error? Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have set `allow-credentials="true"` in your cors configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the problem I got before, you could see any article [here](https://devdojo.com/ketonemaniac/doing-spring-securitys-csrf-tokens-the-right-way-with-react)

In short (see the last section),

> ...Browsers have a "Same Origin Policy" that could be overridden with something called CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)... You could allow localhost:3000 as an "allowed origin" so that it won't be blocked by the browser.

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        };
    }
```